# Changing column data type from chr to date?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 43,000 rows that looks like this:

```
    dat <- data.frame(RecordNumber=1:n, 
    +     date=c("2/2/21 14:20","2/2/21 14:30", "2/2/21 14:40", "2/2/21 14:50", "2/2/21 15:00", "2/2/21 15:10"),
    +     airTemp_C = c(2.4, -11.3, -15, -21.1, -8.5, 0.1))
    
    # RecordNumber         date airTemp_C
    # 1            1 2/2/21 14:20       2.4
    # 2            2 2/2/21 14:30     -11.3
    # 3            3 2/2/21 14:40     -15.0
    # 4            4 2/2/21 14:50     -21.1
    # 5            5 2/2/21 15:00      -8.5
    # 6            6 2/2/21 15:10       0.1
```

and I am trying to convert the date column from chr to date/datetime. Because when I visualize the data with shiny/plotly the date is out of order (maybe because its sorting the date column alphabetically since its a chr datatype not date? Not sure, thats what Im trying to figure out).

I've tried formatting the cells in Excel, I've tried lubridate's parse_date_time(), & base-R's strptime(), however the lists always return NA for all 43,000 of my date rows. Any ideas why this may be?

```
    df$date <- strptime(df$date, format = "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S", tz="MST")
```

reassigns the entire date column as NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `%S`.  It may also be better to use `POSIXct` along with the fact that the sep is not `-` and it is `/`

```
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date, format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', tz = 'MST')
```

-output

```
dat$date
[1] "2021-02-02 14:20:00 MST" "2021-02-02 14:30:00 MST" "2021-02-02 14:40:00 MST" "2021-02-02 14:50:00 MST" "2021-02-02 15:00:00 MST"
[6] "2021-02-02 15:10:00 MST"
```

If we want to convert to `Date` class, it should be wrapped with `as.Date`

---

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dat$date <- mdy_hm(dat$date)
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(RecordNumber = 1:6, date = c("2/2/21 14:20", "2/2/21 14:30", 
"2/2/21 14:40", "2/2/21 14:50", "2/2/21 15:00", "2/2/21 15:10"
), airTemp_C = c(2.4, -11.3, -15, -21.1, -8.5, 0.1)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @milo in the `lubridate`. I used `df` instead of `dat` ..  Sorry.  a typo.  if you haven't created the 'df' object, it is a function in base R and thus returns NA

Comment: @milo I couldn't reproduce that issue with `mdy_hm` though.  Maybe you applied the `mdy_hm` on the Datetime converted column